# MVC webapp Project not deploying to tomcat webapps directory may be a pom.xml issue using eclipse run on server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, spring-mvc, pom.xml

I am trying to test my java MVC application and using eclipse tomcat server integration, but having problems with the deployment. When I use the convenient run on server option in eclipse, It opens a webpage browser in eclipse and is showing a 404 page. I dont know much about the pom file, it might be the issue. I dont see the war file deployed to the webapps folder in tomcat either. Firstly, where in eclipse can I see the warfile, secondly, why is it not being copied to the tomcat webapps folder. Below is my pom file:

```
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SpringChartsterMVC</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringChartsterMVC</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

   <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.14</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>

</dependencies>

  <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

Comment: Your pom file will help you to get the dependencies. Did you get a target folder?  Maybe the error 404 is related to the mapping. Can you provide the URL and the mapping used? Since you are running from eclipse, you will not get the .war in your webapps folder.

Comment: You can check your deployment path by double clicking your server in Eclipse's Servers view

Comment: I doubt the pom is relevant unless you see `ClassNotFoundException` in your startup log. Note that doing the `run on server` in eclipse doesn't use your Tomcat installation directory to deploy the the web applications. It creates its own instance to run somewhere else.